# Specifying columns in jpql select causes casting error

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

When I specify columns in my jpql/jpa 2.0 query, i.e. `select p.id, p.lastName, p.firstName from Profile p where p.group = :group` I get the following error: `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.profs.ws.Profile...` Anyone know how to resolve this casting issue?

The `Profile` entity class itself has properties of the following types: `String, int, and Collection`. The properties I'm selecting in the query are either of the type `String` or `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify properties of an object, JPA returns the list of `Object[]`. You can cast the return value to `List<Object[]` instead of `List<Profile>` to avoid the `ClassCastException`. If you are using Hibernate as JPA provider, you can map the select clause to a new object. See [select clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#queryhql-select) documentation for details.

Comment: I agree, but JPA supports the "map the select clause to a new object" with any provider, not just Hibernate. I think the term used for the container class is a "Constructor Object", but I don't remember at the moment.